# /bin/sh: 1: crond: not found when cron already installed

Tags: python, docker, cron

I have a dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9.12-bullseye

COPY . .

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install cron -y

RUN crontab crontab

CMD  python task.py && crond -f
```

And a crontab

```
* * * * * python /task.py
```

I keep running into the `error /bin/sh: 1: crond: not found` when I run the docker file. Docker build is fine.

Anyone knows why this happens? If I use `python:3.6.12-alpine` everything works fine but with `python:3.9.12-bullseye`, i keep getting that error.

Comment: In Ubuntu and Debian it's `cron`, in Alpine and CentOS, it's `crond`. What a nuisance! https://discourse.chef.io/t/coding-style-abstracting-cron-vs-crond/3115

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a look for debian series cron.service, you could see next:

```
[Unit]
Description=Regular background program processing daemon
Documentation=man:cron(8)
After=remote-fs.target nss-user-lookup.target

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/cron
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/cron -f $EXTRA_OPTS
IgnoreSIGPIPE=false
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

From `ExecStart=/usr/sbin/cron -f $EXTRA_OPTS`, I guess unlike `alpine`, the main program on such debian series linux could be `cron` not `crond`.

(PS: `python:3.9.12-bullseye` based on debian, while `python:3.6.12-alpine` based on alpine)